# Are there any performance advantages to using "const" instead of "let" or "var" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was wondering if, when declaring a constant in JavaScript, does this help optimize the program in any way? I understand that "making assumptions about code" is the way that engines optimize code, so I would imagine making variables into constants would potentially make that easier? I don't imagine this would mean much for Objects or Arrays, since their content can still be modified, but maybe for Strings?

Comment: Most importantly, it allows the developers reading the code to understand it (and the author's assumptions) faster.

Comment: If there was any performance benefit on any one of them, it would probably be very, very negligible.

Comment: Optimisers will always be able to take advantage of immutability. Structures can be stored more simply in memory when it's known in advance that they're immutable. Whether or not your optimiser actually uses this for performance optimisation is probably dependent on the engine version. If you were declaring a const in a log loop there'd probably be some appreciable performance benefit. However as @bergi says, appropriate usage of const is of far greater benefit than any performance gain you might get.